# Dynamic C code execution: memory references

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel, dynamic-code, dynamic-execution

tl;dr : I'm trying to execute dynamically some code from another snippet. But I am stuck with handling memory reference (e.g. `mov 40200b,  %rdi`): can I patch my code or the snippet running code so that `0x40200b` is resolved correctly (as the offset `200b` from the code)?

---

To generate the code to be executed dynamically I start from a (kernel) object and I resolve the references using ld.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, subprocess
if os.geteuid() != 0:
    print('Run this as root')
    exit(-1)
with open("/proc/kallsyms","r") as f:
    out=f.read()
sym= subprocess.Popen( ['nm', 'ebbchar.ko', '-u' ,'--demangle', '-fposix'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
v=''
for sym in sym.stdout:
    s = " "+ sym.split()[0]+ "\n"
    off = out.find(s)
    v += "--defsym "+s.strip() + "=0x" +out[off-18:off -2]+" "
print(v)
os.system("ld ebbchar.ko "+ v +"-o ebbchar.bin");
```

I then transmit the code to be executed with through a mmaped file

```c
int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
address1 = mmap(NULL, page_size, PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ , MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
int in=open(argv[2],O_RDONLY);
sz= read(in, buf+8,BUFFER_SIZE-8);
uint64_t entrypoint=atol(argv[3]);
*((uint64_t*)buf)=entrypoint;
write(fd, buf, min(sz+8, (size_t) BUFFER_SIZE));
```

I execute code dynamycally with this code

```c
struct mmap_info *info;
copy_from_user((void*)(&info->offset),buf,8);
copy_from_user(info->data, buf+8, sz-8);
unsigned long (*func)(void)  func= (void*) (info->data + info->offset);
int ret= func();
```

This approch work for code that don't access memory such as `"\x55\x48\x89\xe5\xc7\x45\xf8\x02\x00\x00\x00\xc7\x45\xfc\x03\x00\x00\x00\x8b\x55\xf8\x8b\x45\xfc\x01\xd0\x5d\xc3"` but I have problems when memory is involved.

See example below.

Let's assume i wan't execute dynamically the function vm_close. `Objdump -d -S` returns:

```
0000000000401017 <vm_close>:
{
  401017:   e8 e4 07 40 81          callq  ffffffff81801800 <__fentry__>
    printk(KERN_INFO "vm_close");
  40101c:   48 c7 c7 0b 20 40 00    mov    $0x40200b,%rdi
  401023:   e9 b6 63 ce 80          jmpq   ffffffff810e73de <printk>
```

At execution, my function pointer points to the right code:

```
(gdb) x/12x $rip
0xffffc90000c0601c:     0x48    0xc7    0xc7    0x0b    0x20    0x40    0x00    0xe9
0xffffc90000c06024:     0xb6    0x63    0xce    0x80
(gdb) x/2i $rip
=> 0xffffc90000c0601c:  mov    $0x40200b,%rdi
   0xffffc90000c06023:  jmpq   0xffffc8ff818ec3de
```

**BUT**, this code will fail since:

1) In my context $0x40200b points at the physical address `$0x40200b`, and not `offset 200b` from the beginning of the code.

2) I don't understand why but the address displayed there is actually different from the correct one (0xffffc8ff818ec3de != ffffffff810e73de) so it won't point on my symbol and will crash.

Is there a way to solve my 2 issues?

Also, I had trouble to find good documentation related to my issue (low-level memory resolution), if you could give me some, that would really help me.

---

<s>Edit: Since I run the code in the kernel I cannot simply compile the code with `-fPIC` or `-fpie` which is not allowed by gcc (`cc1: error: code model kernel does not support PIC mode`)</s>

**Edit 24/09:**
According to @Peter Cordes comment, I recompiled it adding `mcmodel=small -fpie -mno-red-zone -mnosse` to the Makefile (`/lib/modules/$(uname -r)fixed/build/Makefile`)
This is better than in the original version since the generated code before linking is now:

```
0000000000000018 <vm_close>:
{
  18:   ff 15 00 00 00 00       callq  *0x0(%rip)        # 1e <vm_close+0x6>
    printk(KERN_INFO "vm_close");
  1e:   48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi        # 25 <vm_close+0xd>
  25:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  2a <vm_close+0x12>
}
  2a:   c3                      retq   So thanks to rip-relative addressing
```

Thus I’m now able to access the other variables on my script…

Thus, after linking I can successfully access my variable embedded within the buffer.

```
40101e: 48 8d 3d e6 0f 00 00    lea    0xfe6(%rip),%rdi        # 40200b
```

Still, one problem remains:

The symbol I want to access (`printk`) and my executable buffer are in different address spaces, for exemple:

```
printk=0xffffffff810e73de:
Executable_buffer=0xffffc9000099d000
```

But in my `callq` to `printk`, I have only 32 bits to write the address to call as an offset from `$rip` since there is no `.got` section in the kernel. This means that printk *has* to be located within `[$rip-2GO, $rip+2GO]`. But this is not the case there.

Do I have a way to access the printk address although they are located more than 2GO away from my buffer (I tried to used `mcmodel=medium` but I haven't seen any difference in the generated code), for instance by modifying gcc options so that the binary actually have a `.got` section?

Or is there a reliable way to force my *executable* and *potentially-too large-for-kmalloc* buffer to be allocated in the `[0xffffffff00000000 ; 0xffffffffffffffff] range?` (I currently use `__vmalloc(BUFFER_SIZE, GFP_KERNEL, PAGE_KERNEL_EXEC);` )

---

**Edit 27/09:**
I succedded in allocationg my buffer in the `[0xffffffff00000000 ; 0xffffffffffffffff]` range using the *non exported* `__vmalloc_node_range` function as a (dirty) hack.

```c
IMPORTED(__vmalloc_node_range)(BUFFER_SIZE, MODULE_ALIGN,
                MODULES_VADDR + get_module_load_offset(),
                MODULES_END, GFP_KERNEL,
                PAGE_KERNEL_EXEC, 0, NUMA_NO_NODE,
                __builtin_return_address(0));
```

Then, when I know the address of my executable buffer and the address of the kernel symbols (by parsing `/proc/kallsyms`), I can patch my binary using `ld`’s option `--defsym symbol=relative_address` where `relative_address = symbol_address - buffer_offset` .

Despite being extremely dirt, this approach actually works.

But I need to relink my binary each time I execute it since the buffer may (and will) be allocated at a different address. To solve this issue, I think the best way would be to build my executable as a **real** position independent executable so that I can just patch the global offset table and not fully relink the module.

But with the options provided there I got a rip-relative address but no got/plt. So I'd like to find a way to build my module as a proper PIE.

This post is getting huge, messy and we are deviating from the original question. Thus, I opened a new simplified post [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58131500/compile-a-kernel-module-as-a-position-independant-executable). If I get interesting answers, I'll edit this post to explain them.

---

Note: For the sake of simplicity, safety tests are not displayed there

Note 2: I am perfectly aware that my PoC is very unusual and can be a bad practice but I'd like to do it anyway.

Comment: Is what you are executing shellcode? Or are you trying to essentially download "source code" at runtime and execute that instead?

Comment: Try to use a rip-relative addressing mode and `lea` instead of `mov` to load addresses.

Comment: Yup, if you want to mmap the code to whatever random address the kernel chooses, it needs to be position-independent.  So compile with `-fpie`.  (Because you don't want to implement runtime fixups for relocations, or even parse a symbol table.)

Comment: @Nina You can see it as downloading "source code" and executing it at runtime.

Comment: @PeterCordes @fuz Yes, this seems the way to go. But I can't  do that since gcc disallow `-fPIC`or `-fpie` for kernel modules (`cc1: error: code model kernel does not support PIC mode`).

Comment: @MaximeB.: Position-independent code works at *any* address range, including the range used by the kernel.  I think `-fpie -mno-red-zone -mno-sse`  should work as an alternative to `-mcmodel=kernel`.  i.e. let GCC use the small-PIE memory model.  Although I'm not sure the kernel internally uses a GOT or PLT so if your code ends up trying to use those you might still have a problem.  Might work for *this* example though.

Comment: @PeterCordes Post edited to take into consideration your comment

Comment: Can you get the kernel to map your object within 2GB of the code you want it to call, so a call rel32 *can* reach?  Otherwise try `-mcmodel=huge` or something to assume that everything is 64-bits away.  I think medium allows large data but not large code.